# Powershell- Function call is not working in the add_click method. Please advice

Tags: function, powershell, button, method-call

I am trying to call function OKButtonEvent inside the on click event but whenever I am clicking on OK button nothing happens. I have created checkboxes and on selected checkboxes, I am calling different-different powershell scripts but seems not working. I have tried different -2 things but nothing works. One question if I do select 3 checkboxes then during the on click event of OK button all conditions based on 3 selected checkboxes will execute?

Below is my script:

```
function Test-AnyButtonChecked
{
    if ($checkbox1.Checked -or $checkbox2.Checked -or $checkbox3.Checked -or $checkbox4.Checked) 
    {
            $OKButton.Enabled = $true
    }
    else 
    {
            $OKButton.Enabled = $false
    }
}

function OKButtonEvent
{
    if ($checkbox1.Checked)
    {
        echo "hi CB1"
        & ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName)+"\abc.ps1")
    }
    if ($checkbox2.Checked)
    {
        write-host "hi CB2"
        & ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName)+"\bcd.ps1")
    }
    if ($checkbox3.Checked)
    {
        & ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName)+"\cde.ps1")
    }
    if ($checkbox4.Checked)
    {
        & ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName)+"\def.ps1")
    }
}


function checkbox_test
{
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")



    # Set the size of your form
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.width = 1000
    $Form.height = 700
    $Form.Text = ”ABC Scan”

    # Set the font of the text to be used within the form
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12)
    $Form.Font = $Font

    # create your checkbox 
    $checkbox1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $checkbox1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,30)
    $checkbox1.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(250,50)
    $checkbox1.Text = "OS Scan"
    $checkbox1.Checked = $true
    $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox1)

    # create your checkbox 
    $checkbox2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $checkbox2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,90)
    $checkbox2.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(250,50)
    $checkbox2.Text = "ARP Scan - Publisher"
    $checkbox2.Checked = $true
    $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox2) 

    # create your checkbox 
    $checkbox3 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $checkbox3.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,150)
    $checkbox3.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(350,50)
    $checkbox3.Text = "ARP Scan - Display Name"
    $checkbox3.Checked = $true
    $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox3)

    # create your checkbox 
    $checkbox4 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $checkbox4.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,210)
    $checkbox4.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(250,50)
    $checkbox4.Text = "File Scan GCI"
    $checkbox4.Checked = $true
    $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox4) 

    


    # Add an OK button
    $OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(400,550)
    $OKButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.add_Click({$button_click_1})
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)
    #$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton

    #Add a cancel button
    $CancelButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(600,550)
    $CancelButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40)
    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})
    $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

    ###########  This is the important piece ##############
    #                                                     #
    # Do something when the state of the checkbox changes #
    #######################################################
    $checkbox1.add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonChecked })
    $checkbox2.add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonChecked })
    $checkbox3.add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonChecked })
    $checkbox4.add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonChecked })


    $button_click_1={OKButtonEvent}

    # Activate the form
    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()
}

#Call the function
checkbox_test
```

Comment: `$button_click_1` has a value of `$null` by the time you assign it to the Click handler.     `$OKButton.add_Click(${function:OKButtonEvent})` should do :)

Answer (score -1):

So I made this app for a scanner at work. It reads barcodes and makes a list of them. And then when you want the labels printed out....app helps us out by doing that automatically,...

Try it... put some numbers or words or letters in there...

```
     
     #$aNewSheet = [autoPrintForm]::new() 
     $aNewSheet = [autoPrintForm]::new(185)
```

Or just look at this...

```
$this.autoButton is of a type
[object]$autoButton in a powershell class...think
$this.autoButtonX as
[int]$autoButtonX or as
$this.SautoButtonX
is the X size while
$this.PautoButtonX
is the X point on the form.
```

in your class

```
class someFormWithBoxes
{
 [object]$OformP
 [object]$autoButton
 [int]$SautoButtonX
 [int]$SautoButtonY
 [int]$PautoButtonX
 [int]$PautoButtonY
 #.....keep going
 #you can list as many things as you want...any object in c# 
 #usually have some functionality in powershell code as types
 
[void]startForm()
{...#create a form}
[void]addAutoButton()
{
    
   
    
    $this.autoButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $this.autoButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($this.autoButtonX,$this.autoButtonY)
    $this.autoButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($this.RbuttonSizeX,$this.RbuttonSizeY)
    $this.autoButton.Text = 'AUTO'
     $this.autoButton.backcolor = "indianred"
    $this.formP.Controls.Add($this.autoButton)
    
    $thisAUTOBUTTON = $this 
    $this.autoButton.add_click({
        $thisAUTOBUTTON.autoClick()
        }.GetNewClosure())

}
autoclick()
{#your code here referencing the objects defined in the class}
}
```

#end of class

And use a similar workflow to control the entire form and its property variables.
Since you are working with checkboxes you should just look those up and follow a similar workflow. [Examine the Constructors, Properties, Methods, and Events on the left bar on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)  in order to get a deeper grip of the items and objects used by your operating system.

Comment: There's a glaring problem in the code in the question, which the comment on the question identifies.
It is unclear how your answer relates to this problem and to the question in general, given that your answer contains entirely unrelated code.